# How do i stop this ability replacing special slabs with stone slabs?

Tags: java, bukkit

This ability here works perfectly, except that whenever a victim stands on standstone slabs or any other kind, they are replaced with stone slabs. This only happens with slabs, e.g. sandstone stairs will be replaced with sandstone stairs after the ability.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractBlockEarthSpike(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    final Player player = event.getPlayer();
    int selected = player.getInventory().getHeldItemSlot();
    if (selected == 5){
        if (player.getFoodLevel() > 9){
            Block target = (Block) player.getTargetBlock((Set<Material>) null, 15).getLocation().getBlock();
            List<Entity> victims = (List<Entity>) target.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(target.getLocation(), 2, 2, 2);
            player.getWorld().playEffect(target.getLocation().clone().add(0,1,0), Effect.SMOKE, 10);
            for (Entity victim : victims){
                if (victim instanceof LivingEntity){
                    victim.setVelocity(new Vector(0,1,0));
                    ((LivingEntity) victim).damage(2,player);
                    victim.setVelocity(new Vector(0,1,0));
                    final Block block1 = victim.getLocation().getBlock();
                    final Block block2 = victim.getLocation().clone().add(0,1,0).getBlock();
                    final Material type1 = block1.getType();
                    final Material type2 = block2.getType();
                Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(MagictgCraft.that, new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        block1.setType(Material.STONE);
                        player.getWorld().playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.EXPLODE, 10, 5);
                        int count = 0;
                        while (count < 20){
                            player.getWorld().playEffect(block1.getLocation().clone().add(0.5,0.5,0.5), Effect.LAVA_POP, 10);
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                },3);
                Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(MagictgCraft.that, new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        block2.setType(Material.STONE);
                        player.getWorld().playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.EXPLODE, 10, 5);
                        int count = 0;
                        while (count < 10){
                            count = count + 1;
                            player.getWorld().playEffect(block1.getLocation().clone().add(0.5,0.5,0.5), Effect.LAVA_POP, 10);
                        }
                    }
                },5);
                Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(MagictgCraft.that, new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        block2.setType(type2);
                    }
                },8);
                Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(MagictgCraft.that, new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        block1.setType(type1);
                    }
                },10);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I think its because types 1 & 2 don't get the subtype assigned to them (which is wierd because as i said, stairs are not affected by this)
How do i make it assign the subtype for types 1 & 2?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to also save and set the blocks data. The Block class contains the methods getData() and setData() which contain a byte that specifies the exact type of block to use. If you were to look at an [ID list](http://minecraft-ids.grahamedgecombe.com) of minecraft blocks you will see some items that have their ID followed by a colon and another number:

```
1:1
1:2
```

Which represent two different types of blocks. So when you get the material from the block, you'll also want to get the byte data:

```
byte data = block.getData();
```

And then when you're setting another block to this type you'll need to set it's data:

```
block2.setData(data);
```